# What are all the hidden list URL's for WSS 3.0 and MOSS?

Tags: sharepoint, moss, web-parts

For example, I have a MOSS publishing page where a user added a web part and I'm unable to remove that web part due to how the layout is rendered.  I cant access the small drop down menu to "delete" the web part.

I know there is a ton of unpublished list views that exist and was wondering if we could get a comprehensive list of them here, and maybe find the one that will also solve my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey for removing a webpart, you can just append the query string Contents=1 to the webpart page url.

i.e. "http://localhost/sites/SiteCollection/default.aspx?Contents=1" will show you the webpart maintenence page for the webpart page "http://localhost/sites/SiteCollection/default.aspx". Here you can remove the webparts.

Answer (score 2):

From Heather Solomon's blog:
http://www.heathersolomon.com/blog/articles/sp07urls.aspx

Is there some way to make a wiki here?

Comment: Fantastic, thats what I was looking for.  This is a community wiki.  However, I don't know if Heather would like it if we pulled content from her site.  Hmmm.